Add specific product attributes terms slug as a CSS class in Woocommerce
I'm trying to add the attribute value names of a product attribute as classname for each item.
For example, I have a "Mood" attribute and the value names are "Happy", "Chill", "Energized", "Focused" and "Sleepy". I just need to wrap each of the attribute value names in a span tag and add the individual class like this:
Mood: <span class="attribute-chill">Chill</span> <span class="attribute-sleepy">Sleepy</span>

This is the code I have which displays the attributes, but I just need the css classes to be added.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_applications_attribute_pa_mood', 5 );
    
    function display_applications_attribute_pa_mood() {
        global $product;
    
        $mood = $product->get_attribute('pa_mood');
        
        if ( $mood ) {
            printf('<span class="attribute-mood">%1$s</span>', $mood );
        }
}


The following will, for specific defined product attributes, display each term name embedded in a <span> tag with the correct desired class property value:
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_application_attributes', 5 );
function display_application_attributes() {
    global $product;

    // Define your desired product attribute taxonomies to be displayed
    $attribute_taxonomies = array('pa_mood', 'pa_potency'); 

    // Loop through defined taxonomies
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        // Get term names coma separated  string
        $term_names = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
        
        if ( $term_names ) {
            $output_terms = array(); // Initialize

            // Loop through term names
            foreach ( explode(', ', $term_names) as $term_name ) {
                $output_terms[] = sprintf( '<span class="attribute-%s">%s</span>', 
                    sanitize_title($term_name), $term_name );
            }
            printf( '<div><strong>%s:</strong> %s</div>', 
                wc_attribute_label($taxonomy), implode(' ', $output_terms) );
        }
    }
}

It should work as you expect.

Addition (based on your comment):
Showing only one term (and if more, the remaining count):
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_application_attributes', 5 );
function display_application_attributes() {
    global $product;

    // Define your desired product attribute taxonomies to be displayed
    $attribute_taxonomies = array('pa_mood', 'pa_potency'); 

    // Loop through defined taxonomies
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        // Get term names coma separated  string
        $term_names = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
        
        if ( $term_names ) {
            $term_names   = (array) explode(', ', $term_names);
            $terms_count  = count($term_names) - 1;
            $term_name    = current($term_names);
            $count_string = $terms_count > 0 ? ' (+' . $terms_count . ')' : '';

            printf( '<div><strong>%s:</strong> <span class="attribute-%s">%s%s</span></div>', 
                wc_attribute_label($taxonomy), sanitize_title($term_name), $term_name, $count_string
            );
        }
    }
}

It should work as you expect.

@loictheaztec thank you so much. This was perfect.  Just one more thing if I may... Is there anyway to show just one attribute name?  (Even when there are multiple attributes assigned). Example:  Mood: Chill (+2) or just Mood: Chill

@MiguelGomes Added an addition for that…

Thanks again... What if I wanted these attributes to also show in the Cart/Mini-Cart and Checkout pages, below the Product name?

@MiguelGomes If you wanted these attributes to also show in the Cart/Mini-Cart and Checkout, you should first search, try and ask a new related detailed question.

I did search and could not find anything that worked.  This is why i asked on here.

@MiguelGomes See this answer or this answer adapting your code.

I did try that solution but as I said it didn't work.   Also that code was from 5 years ago.  Trust me, I do my research before asking for help.

@MiguelGomes The code from 5 years ago still works… Now it depends on your theme, on the fact if you are using cart/checkout bocks or not, on the product type added to cart and many different things… So your question can't be answered as a comment from a comment question.
